# WebStorm: Update/Upgrade TypeScript (bundled)

Tags: typescript, upgrade, webstorm, updates

How can I generally update/upgrade the bundled version:

[image]

**Please consider**: I'dont want to edit and change to a custom version manually like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WebStorm 2016.3** autodetects your typescript version from local `node_modules`

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without upgrading WebStorm. What is exactly the downside of using a custom version manually? This way the typescript version gets upgraded every time you use

```
npm update -g
```